# Name fields in Profile are Billing not Default

Tags: civievent

On a WordPress site with CiviCRM 5.20.1 we have a Profile used for Event Registration. In that Profile we have "Individual: First Name" and "Individual: Last Name"

The problem is that if I register using my name John Doe and I pay with my employer's credit card and his name is George Washington then on the Thank You screen it shows George Washington as my First and Last Name and then my personal address and other details.

How can we have it show my name and not my employer's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that is a fixed regression - https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/release-notes/5.20.3.md